# Capturing stderr of subprocesses

Tags: elisp, process, error-handling, subprocess

I'm trying to capture stderr separately from stdout for a (synchronous) process run from emacs. I've found one way of doing it based on some code copied from emacs' `shell-command` function (I don't want to use `shell-command` directly because there is no need for a shell and `shell-command` puts stdout into a buffer):

```el
(defun helm-dash-sql (db-path sql)
  "Run the sql command, parse the results and display errors"
  (helm-dash-parse-sql-results
   (with-output-to-string
     (let ((error-file (make-temp-file "helm-dash-errors-file")))
       (call-process "sqlite3" nil (list standard-output error-file) nil
                     ;; args for sqlite3:
                     db-path sql)

       ;; display errors, stolen from emacs' `shell-command` function
       (when (and error-file (file-exists-p error-file))
         (if (< 0 (nth 7 (file-attributes error-file)))
             (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*helm-dash-errors*")
               (let ((pos-from-end (- (point-max) (point))))
                 (or (bobp)
                     (insert "\f\n"))
                 ;; Do no formatting while reading error file,
                 ;; because that can run a shell command, and we
                 ;; don't want that to cause an infinite recursion.
                 (format-insert-file error-file nil)
                 ;; Put point after the inserted errors.
                 (goto-char (- (point-max) pos-from-end)))
               (display-buffer (current-buffer))))
     (delete-file error-file))))))
```

However I suspect it could be done better in two ways:

1. It seems like this should be a solved problem and emacs should have a function that just "does the right thing" with stderr, but I can't find one. Is there such a function?
2. Every time a process is run `shell-command` creates (and later deletes) a temp file in which to store stderr. We are slightly concerned that this could have a performance impact because multiple processes are run for every keypress while inside this `helm` command. Is this likely to be an issue, and if so what is the best way around it?

---

For anyone curious: this is for [`helm-dash`](https://github.com/areina/helm-dash). The exact code I'm currently using is in [this pull-request](https://github.com/areina/helm-dash/pull/82/files).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is fixed in Emacs 25, where you can use the `make-process` function with the `:stderr` argument.  I don't think there's anything suitable in Emacs 24.

Comment: Is there a synchronous version of `make-process`? Or am stuck with choosing between the horrifying hack in the OP versus some kind of horrifying busy-loop/polling hack to block until the process exits?